# Structure of Question

Tags: questions

Today, in "#BBCAskThis" session of BBC news some questions about "School Reforms" were flashed. I am unable to have understood the question structure in this question:

"Surely the curriculum should be the same in each school to ensure equality?"

Notwithstanding the absence of any question word, it is a question.  Could you explain what type of question is this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask a question by  saying any statement with a rising pitch at the end, usually on the last word,  and you indicate this by writing a question mark at the end. Examples:

And your name is?

So we're good?

My name is Alan?

George is fat?

My answer is terrible?

Surely the world be a better place if everyone got together and lived in harmony?

Mom?

Many times these questions expect an answer of yes or no, but not always (And your name is?).

Comment: thanks. Please let me know have I used "Notwithstanding" correctly in my question? I think I should have used some other word instead of "Notwithstanding".

Comment: Your  use of [notwithstanding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/notwithstanding) is perfect.